# Fixed height of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in another view. I want to make the height of the UITabeView constant. I have variable number of rows, but  I want the height of the UITableView constant so that it does not hide the views below it when the rows increase. how do I do this? I tried setting the autoresizingmask but that did not help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried setting TableView's frame?

Comment: Yes I did. Though the table view got truncated the parent view extended.

Comment: Sorry never mind, setting the frame solved it. I wasnt setting the autoresizing of the parent correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

and initialize the frame with the width and height you want.

The style can be one of the following options:
UITableViewStylePlain
UITableViewStyleGrouped

I recommend reviewing [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

[EPyLEpSY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039901/epylepsy) is correct.

```
CGRect tbFrame = [myTableView frame];
tbFrame.size.height = 100;
[myTableView setFrame:tbFrame];
```